# Dividing GCD algorithm for execution in a parallel environment

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, greatest-common-divisor

I wonder if it is possible to divide GCD algorithm for multiple numbers into chunks and than forward them for processing.

I know how to implement this algorithm recursively, but cannot figure out how to split it into work tasks.

Please explain if it is possible, just in pseudocode or any language you know.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: GCD(a, b, c, d) = GCD(GCD(a, b), GCD(c, d))

Comment: @maraca in this case we have to do the final calculation at the end and nodes are responsible for calculating only GCD for two numbers, but finally all heavy computations will be performed by a single merge node.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would need to split this algorithm into multiple threads.  It runs in O(logn) time and O(1) space as is.  Are you computing GCD's of _very_ large numbers?

Comment: @bxfvgekd that property lets you split it into blocks of work of any way you want, including into a few very big pieces, for example as many as you have nodes.